# gdb : examining whatis to intelligently print values

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I want to write a gdb function to print the value of something depending upon the type of it's argument, something like :

```
define psmart
  if (whatis $arg0) =~ vector
    pvector   // stl-views
  else if (it's a pointer)
    p*
  else
    p
  end
end
```

I am currently unable to somehow examine the output of whatis within a gdb function. Please point me how one can do this (or alternate tools that give more power/control).

Answer (score 2):

> Please point me how one can do this (or alternate tools that give more
>   power/control)

Maybe you should not write this gdb function at all. Instead, use gdb [pretty-printers](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport) in Python. Once you configured it, `print` command will detect STL containers without any efforts from your side and output them in a more human-readable form as **stl-views** do.

Comment: thanks, i still have to try this (some network permissions on my dev machine prevent svn/http connections) but this might work

Comment: by the way, any direct ways (within gdb) to do such custom enhancements (or do I have to learn python for gdb scripting?)

Comment: No, you do not have to learn Python, just follow instructions on how to setup pretty-printers. Or use any distr (Fedora 11+) with already configured gdb with pretty-printers.